# HTTP request status_code 0.0 or null in React Native via Sentry

Tags: http, react-native, request, fetch, sentry

I'm finding the following errors in many reports on my Sentry app:

[image: status_code 0.0 and null]

Some requests are failing with a `status_code: 0.0`or `status_code: null`.
It looks very strange to me and I can't understand why and how is it possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem? Now I am getting this error and look like the app is crashing with `readAsText(react-native/Libraries/Blob/FileReader)
fatal
null is not an object (evaluating 't.data')`

Comment: Never solved it. I'm not working with that project anymore though.

Comment: I am now facing this issue and this caused some of my users to crash. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426641/typeerror-null-is-not-an-object-evaluating-t-data-react-native-0-59-5-and