# TypeError - null is not an object (evaluating 't.data') [React Native 0.59.5 Android]

Tags: android, react-native, sentry

After updating my React Native application to 0.59.5, I am seeing several people are crashing in random places for Android users (iOS users are fine). I am using Sentry to track the crash places and the error says:

**TypeError** *readAsText(react-native/Libraries/Blob/FileReader)*

[image]

Following is the stack reported in Sentry dashboard.

[image]

When I check BREADCRUMBS, I see the following.

[image]

I am using `fetch` for HTTP calls. Has anyone faced this problem before? Our API is returning fine. The issue is happening in random places. Is there any situation that triggered this problem? I am using my app the whole day and it is not crashing on me yet. So, if anyone faced this problem before and suggest any solution, I would appreciate a lot.

PS: I tried to simulate errors return from API with 404 and 400 codes. The crash is not this format.

Answer (score -1):

Actually why do you need reactotron for production? Better use that only for develop. Then you won't have this issue:

```
if (__DEV__) {
  import('./ReactotronConfig');
}
```

Comment: Oh is that why some of the API calls return 0 ?

Comment: Hard yo say. And that's really hard to say why reactotron actually cause that. But definitely it should help =)

Comment: Okie sir. Look like i will have to try that and release the app :)

Comment: Hopefully would help!